# Include script tags inside window.load function in head section

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(window).load(function() {      

    // <script src="js/external.js"></script> //

  });    
</script>

</head>
```

How to include script tag(< script src="js/external.js">< /script>) inside window.load function?

Comment: You could use jQuery's `$.getScript`

Comment: could you create a function in the external script and include in the head tags, then just call the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    (function($){    
        $(window).load(function() {      
            $.getScript('js/external.js');
        });
    })(jQuery);    
</script>
```